# c#/.Net Unzip a file with Zlib1.dll

Tags: c#, .net, zlib

Is it possible to extarct a ***".zip"*** file using Zlib1.dll in the c#/.Net?

Regards
Raju

Comment: Once you explain what Zlib1.dll is, your question might become more *answerable*.

Comment: Why not just use SharpZipLib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the native, Windows, compiled form of the zlib library? What about:

- http://www.google.com/search?q=zlib%20.net%20wrapper
- http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23%20zlib